# Can I declare that a property sets a backing field?

Tags: typescript

If I've got the following chunk of code, is there a way to tell the compiler that `this._size` sets `this.__size` (and restricts its type from `Size | undefined` to `Size`)?  Right now, I'm getting an error on the get at `return this.__size` saying that there's a type mismatch between `Size` and `Size | undefined`.  I could assert the type as `return this.__size!;`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible (company style guidelines).

```
class Shape {
  private __size?: Size;
  protected get _size(): Size {
    if (!this.__size)
    {
      this._size = this.onCalculateSize(); // returns `Size`
    }
    return this.__size;
  }
  protected set _size(value: Size)
  {
    this.__size = value;
    this.onSizeChanged();
  }
  protected onSizeChanged(): void { }
  protected onCalculateSize(): Size { return new Size(...); }
}
```

Note that `onCalculateSize` exists to let subclasses have their own implementation without modifying the property logic.

Comment: Typescript does not analize code between methods. `!` is your best choice ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I know that TS doesn't do code analysis, but there are 'decorators' (for lack of a better word) that exist for things like user-defined type guards.

Comment: Yes, but a setter can't be a decorator, you can move the code to another methods and make taht a type guard .. but it seems like overkill ..I can give it a try if you want but I'd go with `!` :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir If the answer is 'no, not currently', that's a perfectly acceptable answer. I wouldn't want to advertise any sort of solution that makes a mountain out of a mole-hill as it were. If there is indeed no existing syntax to handle this, I can think on the problem for a while and suggest syntax + implementation on the github repo.

Comment: There are proposals to allow a custom type assertion method, that is the closes I can think of, but performance prevents implementation (I read this recently but can't find the reference right now)